# What does the 0x??????? in ruby objects' #inspect mean?

Tags: ruby, class

Whenever I make an object instance and call #inspect on it (without that method being overridden), it returns something like `#<ObjectName:0x####### @var=value>`.

What does the `0x#######` mean, and can I use it when writing a custom inspect method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo;end
Foo.new # => #<Foo:0x852e178>
```

It is a memory reference(unique storage location in memory) of object you created.

Comment: Is it accessible and usable in a custom #inspect ?